# iPhone - How may I know if scrollToRowAtIndexPath will scroll something

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, return

I have some things to do at scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation time with a DoThis function.
But sometimes, scrollToRowAtIndexPath with animate=YES does not scroll anything.

So how can I know if the scrolling will be done to be able to force an alternative function DoThisWithNoScrollOccured call after the scrollToRowAtIndexPath call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and see if the RowAtIndexPath you are trying to scroll to is already visible.  If it is already visible, there will be no scrolling.

Comment: That's not always true, depending on the value of `UITableViewScrollPosition`.

Answer (score 4):

Joshua's answer is pretty close, but I've run into situations in which scrolling **will** occur, even if the `indexPath` you wish to scroll to is listed in `indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

For example, if you are scrolling to an indexPath using the scroll position `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`, scrolling will **still** occur when the indexPath is listed in `indexPathsForVisibleRows` - if your `indexPath` is not the first visible `indexPath` and there are more displayable rows after those listed in `indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

In this scenario, the UITableView attempts to scroll the `indexPath` as close as possible to the topmost display position.

I haven't tried it, but I would expect `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom` to have a similar effect if there are displayable rows above the `indexPath` you'll be scrolling to, and the `indexPath` you're scrolling to is not the last visible `indexPath` in `indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Answer (score 3):

With iOS7, neither of these approaches worked for me, probably because of the content inset of my UITableView. `indexPathsForVisibleRows` returned index paths for rows that could not be interacted with because they were behind the `UINavigationBar`. Instead, I did the following:

```
CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (rect.origin.y != self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.tableView.contentInset.top) {
   // scrollToRowAtIndexPath will animate and callback scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation
} else {
   // scrollToRowAtIndexPath will have no effect
}
```